# How to plot data where the sampling window is wider than the sampling period

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

The question is general, but I have a specific example. I am working with aggregated summary data, where I have no access to the underlying raw data. The data is a time series of counts of an event, but the data is reported every week for the preceding four weeks:

- on 29th July I get a count of the number of events that occurred between the 1st and the 28th of July,
- then on the 5th August I get a count of the number of events that occurred between the 8th of July and the 4th of August,

e.g.,

| Start date | End date | Reported on | Events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-28 | 2021-07-29 | 56 |
| 2021-07-08 | 2021-08-04 | 2021-08-05 | 97 |
| 2021-07-15 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-12 | 112 |
| 2021-07-22 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-19 | 105 |
| 2021-07-29 | 2021-08-25 | 2021-08-26 | 102 |
| 2021-08-05 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-02 | 99 |
| 2021-08-12 | 2021-09-08 | 2021-09-09 | 87 |

I would like to represent this data as a line chart (end date as the $x$ axis, events on the $y$ axis), but am unsure how best to present the fact that there will be duplicated events in the time series. At present, I am adding a note to the chart to present this, but feel that there is a better approach that I can use.

Comment: It depends on whether you think there are no errors in the sums, so any event gets counted in precisely four consecutive sums.  If so, you can say  there were $97-56=41$ more events from 2021-07-29 to 2021-08-04 than in 2021-07-01 to 2021-07-07 and similarly for the other weeks.  You can then find which assumed event numbers in the first three or four weeks minimise the volatility of implied weekly event numbers, and use these for your chart.  But this is a very fragile algorithm and will break for example if later counts correct previous counting errors.

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately I cannot be sure that the data is consistent, I believe that some adjustments/corrections are made. I have tried this approach but found that it created periodic oscillation (with a 4 week period) in some time series that had clearly dropped to 0 for several months.